# Can I set Outlook to always Reply to All?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

This may be hidden in the options somewhere but a glance through didn't find it: Is it at all possible to set Outlook so that a click on the "Reply" button (or, as I do, hitting Ctrl-R) will always reply-to-all, rather than reply to one? Or, I suppose, a basic switch of the reply buttons so that the default is reply-to-all, and, for example, I could hit Ctrl-Shift-R instead to reply to one? It's annoying me to constantly have to hit reply-to-all when that's all I do, and I sometimes forget to do it.

Comment: you can modify the ribbon to remove the reply button , that way you  will only have reply to all , i am not sure but i think you can also modify the hotkey so that  alt-R or ctrl-r is binded to reply to all .

Comment: @Shark should be an answer, since it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the ribbon to remove the reply button , that way you will only have reply to all , i am not sure but i think you can also modify the hotkey so that alt-R or ctrl-r is binded to reply to all

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard short-cut listed in [Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Outlook 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-outlook-2010-HP010354403.aspx) is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

See here:

[image: Microsoft Office 2010 Keyboard Shortcut Excerpt]

Comment: Yes, this was noted in my original question.